# X-macro driven C++ template class instantiation

Tags: c++, g++, x-macros

I am trying to instantiate a templatized class based on an X-macro. However, this is giving me syntax errors `error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)`. What is the correct way to instantiate a templatized class from an x-macro?

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#define FOO \
  X(, aaa)    \
  X(int, bbb)  \

template <class T> class A
{
  public:
    A(){ std::cout << "Hello From A\n";}
};

class B
{
  public:
    B() {std::cout << "Hello From B\n";}
};

int main()
{
#define X(a,b) \
  if (0 == strlen(#a)) { \
    printf("%s is empty\n", #b); \
    B b; \
  } else { \
    printf("%s is NOT empty\n", #b); \
    A<a> b; \
  }

  FOO
#undef X

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `X(, aaa)` what do you expect `A<> b;` to do? `What is the correct way...?` What is the code intended to do in the first place? Just don't use X macros and write "Hello from A" and other strings to the output. If you want to _detect if a macro argument is empty_ using preprocessor, or _overload the macro on number of arguments_, that _is_ possible. But it's hard to judge what is "correct" without knowing the goal - I would say this all is not "correct", as you can just write the ouptut you want to write without using macros and overall macros should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't that your syntax is wrong, but rather that both branches of the `if` and `else` get compiled regardless of whether `a` is empty or not. The compiler error will trigger because the `else` branch will try instantiating `A<>`, which isn't legal.

To fix this, you could consider adding a level of indirection. Here's a modified piece of code where the type `AHelper` serves to output something of the proper type.

```cpp
/* By default, use A. */
template <typename... Args> struct AHelper {
    using result = A<Args...>;
};

/* But not if there are no arguments. */
template <> struct AHelper<> {
    using result = B;
};

int main() {

#define X(a,b) \
    AHelper<a>::result b;

    FOO
#undef X

}
```

(Initially, I thought this would be as easy as using `if constexpr` rather than `if`, but in a non-template context the compiler is supposed to evaluate both the `if` and `else` branch and the same compiler error results.)